# Compile maven netbeans project in terminal

Tags: java, linux, maven, netbeans, terminal

I would like compile a Netbeans Maven - Java Application in my linux terminal.

This is because I would like to work with Git CVS and be able to compile the project in a server being IDE independent.

But I'm having trouble understanding really how dependencies work, or that's what I think.

I'm using a simple java application code to connect to a mysql database and get some information.

I'm using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.21/altadb?" + "user=marco&password=Marco19")) {

        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select idCuentaConcentradora, noCliente, nombreCliente, noCuenta, nombreCuenta from altadb.catCuentaConcentradora");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int idCuentaConcentradora = resultSet.getInt("idCuentaConcentradora");
            String noCliente = resultSet.getString("noCliente");
            String nombreCliente = resultSet.getString("nombreCliente");
            String noCuenta = resultSet.getString("noCuenta");
            String nombreCuenta = resultSet.getString("nombreCuenta");
            System.out.println("idCuentaConcentradora: " + idCuentaConcentradora);
            System.out.println("noCliente: " + noCliente);
            System.out.println("nombreCliente: " + nombreCliente);
            System.out.println("noCuenta: " + noCuenta);
            System.out.println("nombreCuenta: " + nombreCuenta);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Then added the mysql-connector-java to the project dependencies, the pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alta.MySQLAccess_Mvn</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySQLAccess_Mvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

If I use the netbeans IDE with clean and build and then run the project there is no error and the information is fetched from the database.

If I try to do the same from terminal I get an error:

```
[marko@mark-laptop MySQLAccess_Mvn]$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MySQLAccess_Mvn 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/marko/NetBeansProjects/MySQLAccess_Mvn/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/marko/NetBeansProjects/MySQLAccess_Mvn/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/marko/NetBeansProjects/MySQLAccess_Mvn/target/MySQLAccess_Mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ MySQLAccess_Mvn ---
[INFO] Installing /home/marko/NetBeansProjects/MySQLAccess_Mvn/target/MySQLAccess_Mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/marko/.m2/repository/com/alta/MySQLAccess_Mvn/MySQLAccess_Mvn/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MySQLAccess_Mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/marko/NetBeansProjects/MySQLAccess_Mvn/pom.xml to /home/marko/.m2/repository/com/alta/MySQLAccess_Mvn/MySQLAccess_Mvn/1.0-SNAPSHOT/MySQLAccess_Mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.866 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-18T18:46:28-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/144M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[marko@mark-laptop MySQLAccess_Mvn]$ java -cp target/MySQLAccess_Mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.marco.mysql.first.test.test 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.marco.mysql.first.test.test.main(test.java:23)
```

Thought since the dependency is being declared in the pom.xml the mysql driver would have been added to the project libraries... but it doesn't.

I would like to achieve the same output from Netbeans from terminal, from build to run.

I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have maven added to the system path then you can simply compile it using the maven commands on the prompt:

```
mvm clean install
```